# Argument list too long in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have read many posts about this error, but I can't seem to figure anything out. For some reason all my rails apps are seeing this error when I run just about anything on the command line (`rails s`, `gem list`, `sudo gem update --system`, etc.)

> /Users/username/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /Users/username/.rvm/bin/gem:
>   Argument list too long
>
> /Users/username/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /Users/username/.rvm/bin/gem:
>   Unknown error: 0

The file it points to looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -s "/Users/username/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31" ]]
then
  source "/Users/username/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31"
  exec gem "$@" #The line it points at
else
  echo "ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/Users/username/.rvm/environments/ruby- 1.9.2-p180@rails31'" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

I'm really new to rails so maybe this is something simple, but I can't make anything of it.

UPDATE:

I reinstalled rvm, but now i get a new error. I was trying to install a different version of ruby and it was all going ok until:

```
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/username/.rvm/usr"  ', please read /Users/username/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p180/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/username/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.3.
ERROR: Error running '/usr/bin/make ', please read /Users/username/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p180/yaml/make.log
Installing yaml to /Users/username/.rvm/usr
ERROR: Error running '/usr/bin/make install', please read /Users/username/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p180/yaml/make.install.log
ruby-1.9.2-p180 - #configuring 
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/username/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/username/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p180/configure.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: can you verify which ruby version you are using with `ruby -v` in the console?

Comment: If you're using rvm, you don't ever want to type in "sudo" -- do you get the errors with non-sudo?

Comment: ruby -v and the non-sudo both give me an error too.

Comment: wow, ruby itself gives this error? That's kind of disturbing.

Comment: please reformat your output and then add the relevant errormessages from the logs that are mentionend in there!

Comment: Pastie /Users/username/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p180/configure.log - or put it here.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to GCC? This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8032980/747923

Comment: I would guess that you're missing a build dependency of some sort. The logs should tell.

Comment: This probably should have been two questions; your original "argument list too long" error message has a different solution from your second "error while running configure" error.

Comment: @sarnold I had the same two issue as Rymo4- 1. I had to reinstall RVM, `rvm implode` 2.Then got the same installation process halting because 1.9.3-p0 expects a non-LLVM version of GCC, which is no longer included in XCode form version 4.2.

`rvm install 1.9.3-p0 --with-gcc=clang`

Comment: @amosel: please add that as an answer -- it covers content not yet answered. (And even though Jesse's answer gets Rymo4 a little further, "remove all your configuration" can usually be improved upon. :)

Answer (score 4):

From the answer's comments:

1. reinstall RVM, rvm implode
2. Then got the same installation process
   halting because 1.9.3-p0 expects a non-LLVM version of GCC, which is
   no longer included in XCode form version 4.2. rvm install 1.9.3-p0 --with-gcc=clang

Comment: I was trying to install RVM, Ruby and Rails for about a full week with an uncanny amount (probably close to 100) different errors that no amount of debugging or reinstallation could fix. The --with-gcc=clang flag was exactly what I needed. I can't thank you enough for your answer. So, this is the best I can do: THANK YOU FROM THE BOTTOM OF MY HEART YOU WONDERFUL MAN!

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling RVM helped me with this issue.

```
rvm implode
    bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem before when I installed RVM (or parts of it) using sudo.

What worked for me was to remove all .rvm from your user's folder, and re-install using non-sudo.

Comment: This is what i did to get rid of that error... but now I get something new. I'll add it to the original question

Answer (score 0):

create a .rvmrc for your project using an up to date version of ruby or try rvm use 1.9.3