# Missing Required Packages? - Including libyaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, homebrew, libyaml

I feel like my computer has some deep seated issues and is 100% against me installing rails/ruby/rvm and the rest on it. Or I'm just incompetent :)

I have installed rvm and ruby without issues. Here is my current setup (Log from Terminal):

```
Mac-mini:rubygems-1.8.25 Riley$ rvm -v

rvm 1.18.15 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Mac-mini:rubygems-1.8.25 Riley$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
```

However rails is a little different..

```
Mac-mini:rubygems-1.8.25 Riley$ rails -v
/Users/Jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Rails 3.2.12
```

So I try to install libyaml:

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
rvm reinstall all --force
```

But then I get this:

```
Missing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, apple-gcc42, libyaml, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, curl-ca-bundle, sqlite.
```

as yellow output, despite it saying the install was successful. Okay, so then I check on rails again.

```
Mac-mini:rubygems-1.8.25 Riley$ rails -v
/Users/Jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Rails 3.2.12
```

Great. Its not working. So I try installing Homebrew to make my life a little easier.

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Installed. Cool.

```
Mac-mini:API Riley$ brew help
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

Huh? And that happens on all `brew` actions, just to be clear.

Now, this is just what I've been facing in the last few hours. I've been trying to get this going for a few days now and I keep getting new errors. I've tried completely removing the Triple R (RVM, Rails and Ruby) and reinstalling and no amount of googling and debugging has seemed to work. I just don't know what to do anymore. I haven't made any progress. I've installed the Triple R on a few other computers, but this computer is just refusing to work with me.

Help to get the Triple R working on my computer would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stemmed from my installation of Ruby. Apparently, as stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9905801/1292230), "a non-LLVM version of GCC" is no longer included in the XCode command line tools.

Installing ruby with:

`rvm install ruby --with-gcc=clang`

Worked and I installed RVM, Ruby and Rails within about 10 minutes, despite it taking me a week of debugging and reinstalling otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

try this answer [Running RVM requirements, Skipping brew update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230092/running-rvm-requirements-skipping-brew-update/15233170#15233170) - it's not the same question, but the solution + explanation are the same.

Comment: Is 2.0.0 stable? I will definitely try that when I can get to that computer next. I have to switch out for a different computer because Ruby wouldn't install.

Comment: ruby 2.0.0-p0 is stable, you should try it out, if you want to setup production then wait for next patchlevel.