# Running RVM requirements, Skipping brew update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, homebrew

When I run the command rvm requirements I get Skipping `brew update`. Why is this happening on Mac 10.8

```
rvm requirements
Installing requirements for osx/10.8/x86_64, might require sudo password
Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.
Doing /usr/local/etc/openssl
```

Comment: can you do `rvm get stable` ?

Comment: Gave me some instructions to update Dependencies which I already had done. It also suggested brew install bash curl git. Tried that got an error. Error: git-1.8.1.5 already installed, it's just not linked. Not sure dhow to link it ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
rvm install 2.0.0 --autolibs=enable
```

You get this message because by default RVM (head at this time) is only detecting available packages (read only mode), it was requested by Homebrew developers that RVM does not automatically use Homebrew to install libraries, we (RVM) are working on making all the output cleaner so it's easy to change to proper mode of integration. You can visit https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1627 to get more details what the number means and what options are planned.