# rvm install ruby 1.9.3 : Missing required packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm trying to switch from Ruby 1.8 to 1.9.3 through RVM :

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

But everytime I have a warning :

```
Missing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, libyaml, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, curl-ca-bundle, sqlite.
```

I tried with

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
```

but nothing better. Everytime I have this warning, and it's preventing me from installing rails 3 (missing libyaml and openssl). Anyone already solved that ? Thanks for your help.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.2

Comment: Check this question if it is helpful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207239/missing-required-packages-including-libyaml

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try running

```
rvm requirements
```

And then:

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config apple-gcc42 libyaml readline libxml2 libxslt libksba openssl sqlite
```

If you still have issues you can check this out - [click here](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/ckaukis/2013/03/05/installing-ruby-200-rvm-and-homebrew-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion)

Comment: Thanks ! I used the link to install Homebrew, and then the brew install command worked for all except libxml2 and libxslt. I "bundle install"ed, then installed rails : not working. I tried again to brew install these 2 and now it worked ! Pfiou ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: if you get `Error: No available formula for apple-gcc42` Error with mountain lion , try `brew tap --repair homebrew/dupes` , then try reinstalling

Answer (score 5):

This is new functionality for RVM 1.19, we will work on improving the messages, for now just try:

```
rvm get head
rvm install 1.9.3 --autolibs=3
```

Comment: it did not because I assumed it is obvious to run `rvm get head` first - updating instructions