# RVM Ruby / Brew installation issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew

When I try to install ruby or brew on my Mac Mini running OSX 10.8.2, I am getting this issue:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx/10.8/x86_64, might require sudo password
Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

I'm not really sure what's going on. Should I be reinstalling XCode to clean up my frameworks?

What is going wrong and how can I fix it? I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but neither google, nor symbolhound can find any results on the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stemmed from my installation of Ruby. Apparently, as stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9905801/1292230), "a non-LLVM version of GCC" is no longer included in the XCode command line tools.

Installing ruby with:

`rvm install ruby --with-gcc=clang`

Worked and I installed RVM, Ruby and Rails within about 10 minutes, despite it taking me a week of debugging and reinstalling otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Do `sudo rvm install 1.9.3`. This should fix your problem.

Comment: A genius, you are. It seems to be working. I will come back if I can get everything else installed. Otherwise I will need you for my next issue :) So, I guess I will be letting you know, either way.

Comment: One thing to note, if you are installing gems and have a similar issue, use `rvmsudo gem install...`. You want to be careful with `sudo`.

Comment: Ah. There is an issue, it seems. When I run `rvm list`, it tells me that there aren't any rvm rubies installed, but when I run `sudo rvm list`, it shows me my installed versions of ruby. However, I can't use any `ruby` commands, now.

Comment: get your list of ruby versions and use: `rvm use 1.9.3` or what ever version you are using

Comment: It can't find the ruby versions with list. And it won't let me `use` with sudo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25725/discussion-between-rileye-and-blaine)

Comment: The problem ended up being that I needed the --with-gcc=clang flag for the installation.