# OpenSSL version issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, rvm

I can't seem to get my computer to use the correct version of OpenSSL. I seem to have done exactly what [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185661/openssl-version-macosx-homebrew) has done and I've tried working through the tutorials [here](http://foodpicky.com/?p=99) and [here](http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html).

After trying to go through all of that, `openssl version` still outputs `OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011`, despite `brew link openssl --force` giving me `Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e`.

What am I supposed to do to install openssl properly? I can't seem to use RoR with the version I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stemmed from my installation of Ruby. Apparently, as stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9905801/1292230), "a non-LLVM version of GCC" is no longer included in the XCode command line tools.

Installing ruby with:

`rvm install ruby --with-gcc=clang`

Worked and I installed RVM, Ruby and Rails within about 10 minutes, despite it taking me a week of debugging and reinstalling otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
rvm get head
rvm install 2.0.0 --autolibs=3
```

rvm will do all the required steps automatically

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I've already tried that. Unfortunately, I've tried a large number of solutions, but without any luck so far.

Comment: are you sure `rvm get head` worked? did it print any warnings? can you show output of: `rvm install 2.0.0 --autolibs=3 --debug`

Comment: It did work without any output, actually. It seems the problem actually stemmed from my ruby installation.