# Issue with gems in RVM, Ruby and Rails installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, openssl

I have been trying to get my dev environment setup on my computer for a number of days now, but without any luck. I've had more error messages than I could care to remember and my installation problems have been anything but consistent.

My current problem is unknown as I don't know where its stemming from.

When I try to check my gem version `gem -v`, the terminal locks up for a couple minutes and then gives me this output:

```
/Users/Riley/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /Users/Riley/.rvm/bin/gem: Argument list too long
/Users/Riley/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /Users/Riley/.rvm/bin/gem: Undefined error: 0
```

The entire contents of that file are as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -s "/Users/Riley/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p0" ]]
then
  source "/Users/Riley/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p0"
  exec gem "$@"
else
  echo "ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/Users/Riley/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p0'" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

And I don't have a clue what its supposed to be, if not that. Checking `which ruby` gives me:

```
/Users/Riley/.rvm/bin/ruby
```

And the problem really seems to come alive when I try to install rails, `gem install rails`:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

** This error has ceased to occur and is now replaced with the above "line 6" error for `gem -v`, however I'm sure it will show up again.

I have also tried all of this:

```
rvm get head --autolibs=3
rvm pkg remove
rvm reinstall all --force
```

and all the other renditions of solutions on SO and many other sites.

I would greatly appreciate someone helping me with this setup as I don't have any solution to my problem outside of google and SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stemmed from my installation of Ruby. Apparently, as stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9905801/1292230), "a non-LLVM version of GCC" is no longer included in the XCode command line tools.

Installing ruby with:

`rvm install ruby --with-gcc=clang`

Worked and I installed RVM, Ruby and Rails within about 10 minutes, despite it taking me a week of debugging and reinstalling otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rvm requirements` and install all the dependencies as specified (openssl being one of them). It should fix your problem.

Comment: How do I install them? Its not `rvm install xxxxx`, right? That doesn't work for me.

Comment: I've figured it out, however the currently pressing problem is the gem path issue.

Comment: Well that is awkward. Sorry, I can't help you with this.

Comment: Its okay. I've actually finally gotten everything installed in one fresh build. The key was building ruby with the flag `--with-gcc=clang`